# Ruby on Rails paperclip multiple upload with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, nested-attributes

I was wondering if someone can help me with file uploading!

I'm trying to upload multiple images using paperclip and having nested attributes.

## **models**

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :trip_images, :dependent => :destroy
end

class TripImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :large => "800x800>", :medium => "500x500>", :thumb => "150x150#" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

## **controller**

```
def create
  @trip = Trip.new(trip_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @trip.save
      format.html { redirect_to @trip, notice: 'Trip was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @trip }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @trip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

def trip_params
  params.require(:trip).permit(
    :user_id,
    trip_images_attributes: [:id, :photo])
end
```

## **view**

```
<%= simple_form_for @trip, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :trip_images do |p| %>
    <%= p.file_field :photo, as: :file, multiple: true %>
  <% end%>

  <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

How do I save multiple images in my trip image database? When I submit the form, nothing gets saved into the database.

Comment: Try changing `trip_images_attributes: [:id, :photo])` to `trip_images_attributes: [:id, :photo => []])`

Comment: And also add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :trip_images` in `Trip` Model.

Comment: Could you post a piece of log with request to the create action?

Comment: @Pavan When I tried this, I get an error `No handler found for [#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9fdc112d98 @tempfile=#...` I also tried @AndreyDeineko's method too. But it only saved 1 record into database.

Comment: hey what's up with the issue? did you get it working in the end?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Hi! Sorry for the late response. I actually had to go through a different route. I used refile gem instead. The issue with the solution you provided is that the user would have to upload 1 image at a time with the link "add another photo". I just couldn't get it working with the code you provided :( :( I was struggling and took me long hours to trying to fix this.

Comment: Ohh, I see. I only now realized, you wanted to upload like multiple file with one click.. Sorry, misunderstood the task. Never done it truly to say (I was always content with one file per click 'add new photo'). Hope you got it working with refile!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I did! I can provide some information when I have some time.. probably post it in a blog or something. I haven't seen too many tutorials on refile. However, I couldn't implement dropzonejs.. that thing is a headache!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko dropzonejs is a nice little feature that I hope to get it working :(

Answer (score 5):

Add `:trip_id` to `trip_images_attributes`:

```
def trip_params
  params.require(:trip).permit(
    :user_id,
    trip_images_attributes: [:trip_id, :id, :photo]) # :_destroy
end
```

Also you can add `:_destroy` if you plan to be able to remove photos.

What you also missed is to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :trip_images` to `Trip` model.

Change your form to something like this:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :trip_images do |tp|
  = render 'trip_photos_fields', f: photo
.links
  %br= link_to_add_association 'Add another photo', f
```

And `_trip_photos_fields.html.haml` partial:

```
  - unless f.object.new_record?
    %br= link_to_remove_association "Delete photo", f
  = link_to image_tag(f.object.photo.url(:medium)), f.object.photo.url, target: '_blank'
  - if f.object.new_record?
    = f.file_field :photo, as: :file
```

Comment: When I tried this, I check my database, and there's only 1 record.  I tried to retrieve this record and this is what I got: `/images/{"id":1,"trip_id":19,"created_at":"2015-07-20T07:36:17.820Z","updated_at":"2015-07-20T07:36:17.820Z","photo_file_name":null,"photo_content_type":null,"photo_file_size":null,"photo_updated_at":null}` in img src tag, using this: `<% @trip.trip_images.each do |img| %><%= image_tag img.to_json %><% end %>` And I tried to save multiple photos in this attempt

Comment: @hellomello so your original issue is solved, now you have another one - there is null instead of photo_file_name.. Do you have imagemagic installed? It is necessary in order for Paperclip to work.

Comment: Well it its not saving multiple uploads that I'm trying to accomplish. It's only saving 1 record. Also, I checked if I have ImageMagick installed by checking the version, and I do. `Version: ImageMagick 6.8.7-7 Q16 x86_64 2013-11-27` by using `convert -version`

Comment: @hellomello to make it save multiple uploads you have  to change your form to actually accept these photos. I'll edit the answer

Comment: I've been looking at the parameters in console, and I've noticed that I'm getting this: `name=\"trip[trip_images_attributes][0][photo][]\";` on all images. So if I uploaded 5 images, all 5 images has that in the parameters trying to save into the database. Also, at the end of the parameters, there's this: `Unpermitted parameter: photo`

Comment: I'm getting an association doesn't exist on trip. Also, what do you mean whitelist not only inside the `trip_images_attributes`? I tried to add it after user_id, but I'm still getting unpermitted parameter. I tried doing this before changing my form. But this method can't allow users to just highlight as many photos to upload?

Comment: this is strange man, but try to debug the unpermitted param. FOr example, use `save!` method which will show you validation errors, use `binding.pry` or any other tool. Can't really say what's wrong from your last descriptions..